# How to fix inconsistency in last layer shape "Error when checking target: expected dense_ to have shape xx but got array with shape yy"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am a newbie to deep learning and TensorFlow and still have problem understanding the relationship between layers and their output. I am working on a binary classification for time series and get the following error. I wonder what is the reason for getting this error and what items should I check in my architecture to avoid getting this:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_68 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (24,)
```

I have a simple dataset with these sizes:

```
xTrain (32,24) # 32 training observations with 24 features
yTrain (32,1) # 32 training binary label (0 or 1)
xTest (16,24) 
yTest (16,1)
```

My architecture looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=24))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, validation_data=(xTest, yTest), epochs=10, batch_size=2)
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               2500      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,601
Trainable params: 2,601
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Since the size of `yTrain` and `yTest` is 1, and in the last dense layer, I set the unit size as 1, I wonder why I get the error that I get array with shape (24,), which is equal to my feature size as error.

Comment: Yes, this seems odd, are you sure that the shapes you gave us are right, and that you are passing x and y correctly? The error would be produced if you passed xTrain as y in model.fit

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted your code and created the datasets with the same shapes. The model correctly starts training so I think you just have a typo/bug somewhere.

My code is this:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

xTrain = np.zeros((32,24)) # 32 training observations with 24 features
yTrain = np.zeros((32,1)) # 32 training binary label (0 or 1)
xTest = np.zeros((16,24))
yTest = np.zeros((16,1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=24))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, validation_data=(xTest, yTest), epochs=10, batch_size=2)
```